# texture loading | wrong color

Tags: opengl

With using texture image, I have created objects in the scene. But, there is a problem ; instead of blue, its colour is green. What is the possible reason to that bug ?

Comment: make sure your pixels in texture file are stored the same way as you defined in `TexImage2D` (current is `GL_RGB`)

Comment: @xiaoyi they are both same.

Comment: @xiaoyi can you look at edit ?

Comment: Most texture color problems are caused by using wrong pixel format. So please try some other formats.

Comment: @xiaoyi my image size is not multiple of 2 ( 254 x 254 ). Is this effect ?

Comment: all modern graphic processors support non power of 2 textures.

Comment: If the lack of the non power of two extension is the problem the texture would turn up white.

Comment: Did you use glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); ? If you didn't, the objects will have the color set in the last glColor() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `GL_BGR` instead.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Comment: Another question, are you using alpha?  If you are, try `GL_RGBA` or `GL_BGRA`.

Comment: @user1947920: If you're loading your data from a BMP file there is a 4th channel in the data format, that may be unused, but still there. So use GL_BGRA for loading BMP files, even if this is to be done without an alpha channel in the internal format.

Comment: @user1947920 You mean the edit that made any actual sample code vanish and the question thus unanswerable?